# Permalink issues with custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have a (hopefully simple) question here.

Built in post type: Category

I have a custom post type: Rights, with a custom Category taxonomy for it (Rights Category).

My issue is using the rewrite slug of `rights/category` is being caught first by the generic `category` rewrite rule. So I am currently stuck using `rights-category`, or `rights/categories` (at least a little more elegant).

Is there any way (besides changing the Category base) to essentially say "Prioritize my custom rewrite rule over the built-in ones"? Last time I looked at Category's registration, I didn't think it was possible to register your own taxonomies before the built-in ones (priority 0), therefore placing your own rewrite rules ahead of WP Core's.

**Note:** I am defining the custom taxonomy and post type within mu-plugins. I also just tried using a priority of 0, and 1, and they seem to work with no repercussions. I'd still like some validation on this, however.

Comment: You can avoid conflict using a singular cpt name with plural archive slug: `register_post_type('right', $args)` where `$args['has_archive'] = 'rights'`. If you use plural cpt name only chance is add a custom rewrite rule, in that case see @cybnet answer. You can do registration for cpt, taxonomy and rewrite rule in same function, hooked on init (priority is not a important).

Comment: I think you misread the question. It's not the post type that is giving me the issue. It's the rewrite rules for Post Categories, that is conflicting with my Rights Categories. Basically, `/category/*` is being searched for before `/rights/category/*` is, in the order of the global `$wp_rewrite`.

Comment: Yes I know. But have you tried? I had, and with my tip it works. [This](http://pastebin.com/1wCiTq1M) is the code I tried and works in a MU plugin. After flushing rules, of course

Comment: @EricHolmes please add your code to your question.

Comment: @G.M. Exactly what I have (almost). The key to having this to work here is your `init` action is set to priority 1. So yes, this is correct, and what I mention above in my question. Want to move that to an answer so I can mark this complete?

Comment: @EricHolmes I've tested with priority 9999 and it works. I've also tested running code on `wp_loaded` (a later hook) and it works again. But if I register post type using plural name: `register_post_type('rights', $args);` without change anything else it fails.

Comment: Very odd, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you define custom rewrite slugs in the registration of a custom taxonomy, you still need to add custom rewrite rules.

```
add_action('init','my_add_rewrite_rules');
function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'rights/category/(.+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?post_type=rights&category=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'rights/category/(.+)/?$' , 'index.php?post_type=rights&category=$matches[1]' , 'top' );
}
```

In order to add the correct rewrite rule I would need the code of the custom post type and custom taxonomy registration. Also, don't forget to flush rewrite rules by visiting WP admin area->settings->permalinks.

I can confirm from my own tests that @G.M. is correct (see first comment to the question). If you register your cpt with the singular name `right` and set the `has_archive` argument to the plurgal slug `rights`, the custom `rewrite` argument in `register_taxonomy` you are using will work without any custom rewrite rules. So you can register the cpt with `register_post_type('right', $args)` where `$args['has_archive'] = 'rights'`. But now you will have:

- domain.com/rights/ -> for archive view
- domain.com/right/a-custom-post/ -> for single custom post view
- domain.com/rights/taxonomy-slug/term-slug/ -> the term archive view

So, I still prefer register the cutom post type with plural slug and add the rewrite rules in order to have a more consistent permalink structure like this (all urls will inclue 'rights' slug):

- domain.com/rights/ -> for archive view
- domain.com/rights/a-custom-post/ -> for single custom post view
- domain.com/rights/taxonomy-slug/term-slug/ -> the term archive view

Comment: Shouldn't need a custom rewrite rule for a WordPress object (post type, taxonomy, etc.), but thanks for the answer! I'm also unsure that this would take precedence over the built-in `category` rewrite rules, unless you called this init action at 0, which is the same as I am doing above (working).

Comment: I suggested that because I had to do it for my own custom taxonomy. Without adding my own rewirte rules, the custom rewrite slug for a custom taxonomy was not working. Anyway, have you tried? The built-in `category` rewrite rules and the one suggested are differents.

Comment: The `'top'` argument adds it to the top of the stack so it would match first if there's a clash... but there shouldn't be a clash since the pattern is unique from the built in category rules, and adding a custom rewrite rule should not be necessary.

Comment: This would work perfectly cybnet. But using the `rewrite` argument in `register_taxonomy` may save you some pain in the future. It seems using a priority of 0 on the `init` function will save you all the hassle :).

Comment: I think I didn't explain well or you didn't understand me. I'm not suggesting to use the custom rewrite rules or the `rewrite` argument in `register_taxonomy`, I'm suggesting to use both. The `rewrite` argument in `register_taxonomy` will create the permalinks, the custom rewrite rules will pass the correct query for that permalinks to Wordpress. Maybe, as @G.M. suggested, is this needed when a plural name is used?. I really don't know why or when this is needed but I needed in a custom project and it seems like you also need it. I've edited the answer to add support for pagination.